# lottie animation causing app crash on device

Tags: swiftui

I am using Lottie to display animations in application and I tried to use this animation
[AnimationURL](https://lottiefiles.com/56978-world-map)

LottieView -

```
struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {

var animationName: String

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    let animationView = AnimationView()
    
    let animation = Animation.named(animationName)
    animationView.animation = animation
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
    animationView.loopMode = .loop
    
    animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    uiView.addSubview(animationView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.heightAnchor),
        animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.widthAnchor)
    ])
    
    animationView.play()
}
}
```

But when I want to display animation, application crashes in *AnimatorNode* file from Lottie library in this function (*Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ce6bff0)*):

```
func updateContents(_ frame: CGFloat, forceLocalUpdate: Bool) -> Bool {
  guard isEnabled else {
      return parentNode?.updateContents(frame, forceLocalUpdate: forceLocalUpdate) ?? false
}
}
```

When I opened *View Hierarchy* after app crash, I received this log -

*Failed to unarchive request data with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}*

On simulator, animation is running normally, but when I build application on device, application is crashing on this animation. Is there any way to fix this and use this animation?

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue.
It doesn't depend on SwiftUI / UIKit thing.
On Simulator it works ok because your simulator has more memory than iPhone does. So maybe your `animation.json` is too hard for current version of Lottie-ios lib. Maybe its good idea to report them, that they should update implementation of lib on iOS side.
Thank you!